# In jquery how do I remove an array element either via index["key"] or value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In **jQuery/JavaScript**, How do I remove an array element?

something like:

```
array.remove(array["key"]);

// or 

array.remove("value")
```

Comment: An array element or an object's property?

Comment: Whether your asking about an Array, or just a plain object, this has been covered many times on StackOverflow. As it is, I can't tell if you want to delete a property, remove an Array item by index, or remove an Array item by value. NARQ IMO.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Judging by your code, it sounds like you want to delete an object's property, which you would do with [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
var obj = { key: "value" };

delete obj["key"];
```

A very useful guide on working with objects in JavaScript can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: delete will leave blank value , you will still need to reload object although you will get blank index which you deleted

Answer (score 28):

For **arrays** use the [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method :

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array.splice(2, 1);
console.log(array); // [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

You could make your own function to remove (the first occurrence of) a certain element in the array :

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(el) {
    return this.splice(this.indexOf(el), 1);
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.remove(4);
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

If you want to remove an item from an **object**, use the `delete` syntax :

```
var a = {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'};
delete a.key1;
console.log(a); // {key2: 'val2'}
```

And yet again you can make your own function to handle this :

```
Object.prototype.remove = function(el) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
        delete this[el];
    }
    return this;
}
var a = {key1 : 'val1', key2: 'val2'};
a.remove('key1');
console.log(a); // {key2: 'val2'}
```

**Update** :

1. Although this was just an example, as @Eric pointed out, it's not a very good idea to modify an object's prototype. So I've re-written examples that do not alter the object's state
2. Added a check if the element exists in the array. If it doesn't exist, the reeturned index would be `-1` and the splice method would remove the last element (the first element from the end of the array). Thanks, @amnotiam!

```
function remove(collection, key) {
    // if the collections is an array
    if(collection instanceof Array) {
        if(collection.indexOf(key) != -1) {
            collection.splice(collection.indexOf(key), 1);
        }
    }
    // it's an object
    else if(collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        delete collection[key];
    }
    return collection;
};
```

And of course, since the question was tagged `jquery`, we can add this function as a jquery plugin :

```
(function($, global, undefined) {
    $.removeElementFromCollection = function(collection,key) {
        // if the collections is an array
        if(collection instanceof Array) {
            // use jquery's `inArray` method because ie8 
            // doesn't support the `indexOf` method
            if($.inArray(key, collection) != -1) {
                collection.splice($.inArray(key, collection), 1);
            }
        }
        // it's an object
        else if(collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            delete collection[key];
        }

        return collection;
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

And then use it like this :

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$.removeElementFromCollection(array, 2); // [1, 3, 4, 5]

var object = {1: 2, 3: 4};
$.removeElementFromCollection(object, 1); // {3: 4}
```

Comment: Since this answer covers all the possible variants (array/object + key/value), can we prettify question and then link every "delete" question here as duplicates?

Comment: It was an example. you can deduce what the arguments are by the actual result, or you can read the postet link to the splice method documentation.  The first argument is the index from where do you want to remove elements, and the second one is the number of elements you want to remove.

Comment: `Object.prototype.remove = ...` - **Don't do that!**. What if my object is `{add: 'val1', remove:'val2'}`?

Comment: `this.splice(this.indexOf(el),1);` will be problematic if the item is not found. As will this `collection.splice($.inArray(key,collection),1);`

Comment: In Chrome at least, if a is an object, delete a.b returns true (i.e. it doesn't return any error) even if a['b'] doesn't exist so it seems the this.hasOwnProperty(el) check is unnecessary. A check to see if el is an object could be useful though.

Answer (score 7):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(2, 1);
```

will remove 1 item from array fruits, position 2, which is `Apple`

Answer (score 2):

`array["key"]` is not the key of an array (there are no associative arrays in javascript, if you come from PHP they might look like them, but they are objects) but the property of an object, i think you can use delete

```
delete array.key
```

Comment: though array[x] (using the variable in "X") is not the same as array.x